# Set UIView's autoresizing mask programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, autoresizingmask

I have to set autoresizingMask programmatically for `UIView`.

I don't know how to implement this.

[image]

Comment: I made a simple tool for this: http://erkanyildiz.me/lab/autoresizingmask you can use it.

Comment: @erkanyildiz thanks for the refresher for the people who no longer want to use autolayout for simple layouts.

Comment: @erkanyildiz that's pretty awesome that tool. Makes you wonder why storyboard doesn't have that in built ey.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

To achieve what you have in that screen shot you need to do the opposite of what DrummerB suggests. You want a fixed top margin so you make every other side flexible like so:

**Objective C:**

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Not setting a side as flexible means that it will be fixed (default behaviour), thats why there is no such thing as UIViewAutoResizingFixedTopMargin (since its the same as not setting UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin)

**Edit for Swift:**

```
view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleRightMargin, .FlexibleLeftMargin, .FlexibleBottomMargin]
```

Credit to Tom Calmon for adding the swift version 1st.

**Swift 5.0 update:**

```
view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]
```

Cheers.

Comment: No one has mentioned WHERE to set this value.  What method(s) are suggested for setting this in?

Comment: @LogicsaurusRex you usually set the autoresizing mask when you are creating the view. It can be set anywhere else though, as long as the view is not nil. It can also be set in InterfaceBuilder

Comment: @LogicsaurusRex as for the methods in objectiveC, you use the dot syntax as shown in my answer or you can use setAutoResizingMask

Comment: @Bharath your edit is wrong. The screen-shot specifies a non flexible width and non flexible height. Not sure how that was approved. Please see my fix.

Answer (score 24):

You have to set the view's `autoresizingMask` property:

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

The possible values are defined in `UIViewAutoresizing`:

```
enum {
   UIViewAutoresizingNone                 = 0,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   = 1 << 0,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth        = 1 << 1,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  = 1 << 2,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    = 1 << 3,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight       = 1 << 4,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin = 1 << 5
};
typedef NSUInteger UIViewAutoresizing;
```

You can set multiple values with the bitwise OR operator `|`.

Comment: i have to set image in top with AspectFit mode. I get the image properly but the AspecFit property is not working like image is in center but the left and right part is cut or out of bound

Comment: While this answer helps those who want to know the possible values of UIAutoResizingMask, the solution provided does not match what is in the screen shot. The top margin should be fixed and every other side left flexible (not width or height, just the sides). See my answer for solution that matches the screenshot

Answer (score 22):

**Swift 2.0:**

```
view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleRightMargin, .FlexibleLeftMargin, .FlexibleBottomMargin]
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4.1:**

```swift
view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]
```

Answer (score 0):

To set flexible Top Margin,Bottom Margin,Left Margin and Right Margin of a UIView write the following code-

```
autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```