# How to set UIView's autoresizing mask programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autoresizingmask

I have to set autoresizingMask programmatically for UIView.

I don't know how to implement this.

[image: Screenshot of autoresizing which i want to implement]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center UIButton programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908510/center-uibutton-programatically)

Comment: 1. Use autolayouts instead of the older autoresizing. 2. 'Autoresizing programatically' has been asked and answered many many times before. Search before posting a new question. Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you need to set it.

```
yourView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you have in that screen shot you need to do the opposite of what DrummerB suggests. You want a fixed top margin and right margin so you make every other side flexible like so:

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

If you want to know the concept very clearly,

[UIView's autoresizing mask programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695343/set-uiviews-autoresizing-mask-programmatically)

[View AutoResizingMask Constant](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW5)

[UIView AutoResizingMask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468389/uiview-autoresizingmask-interface-builder-to-code-programmatically-create-st)

[Autoresizing masks programmatically vs Interface Builder / xib / nib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754851/autoresizing-masks-programmatically-vs-interface-builder-xib-nib)